# camera wont move from one object to another after certain criteria is met keeps going to the right position then back to the old position

Tags: javascript, three.js, leap-motion

Im making a universe with Three.js with the Leap Motion controls but somehow it doesn't switch planets (changes camera position and `lookAt`) after i swipe to left or right because it keeps resetting to the position it starts when you start the webpage as if its stuck on the position of the set position at the begin of the code i have this to set my camera position when i start up the webpage.

```
// camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, $(window).width() / $(window).height(), 0.1, 100000);
camera.position.set(300, 300, 300);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

and in my Loop of the leap motion i have to place the if to check if i swipe to left or right i put this.

```
if(frame.gestures.length > 0) {
       for (var i = 0; i < frame.gestures.length; i++) {
              var gesture = frame.gestures[i];

              if (gesture.type == "swipe") {
                  //Classify swipe as either horizontal or vertical
                   var isHorizontal = Math.abs(gesture.direction[0]) > Math.abs(gesture.direction[1]);
                  //Classify as right-left or up-down
                  if (isHorizontal){
                      if (gesture.direction[0] > 0) {
                         camera.position.set(300, 300, 300);
                         camera.lookAt(moonMesh.position);
                      }
                      else{

                      }
              }
        }
  }
```

I also have to mention im programming in Javascript just to be sure I put it here ^^ my question is how can i change my camera position and focus without it going back to its starting points?

thanks in advance

sincerely Tsukio Akira

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you always focus on moonMesh.position whenever there is a swipe, so it will never NOT lookAt the moonMesh and be at the position of (300,300,300)

Comment: No i set my code so it looks at my scene if i dont do that it will just show a white page with nothing on it not even when i swipe it how can i change this so i can change it my code looks basically in the beginning of execition to the earthMesh but i want it to be able to switch when i have swiped is there a way to do this? Also when i set up the camera is in a different place then the if statement i setup the camera within my function init and my if statement for switching is in my Leap.loop

Comment: Are you sure it's detecting swipes then? The best way to check if each situational criteria is met is logging a message. If you swipe and it doesn't show the message then it could be there. What I meant originally was that if you swiped it would be on moonMesh and never change, I didn't realize that it started on an earthMesh

Comment: Yes i know for certain it detects the swipe because the camera position does change but imediatly goes back to the position i set in my question do you know anything?